# Django rest framework permissions

Tags: permissions, django-rest-framework

I have the following api:

In models.py:

```
class TMyusers(models.Model):
    id = models.OneToOneField('auth.User', primary_key=True)
    device= models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 't_myusers'
        ordering = ('id',)
```

In serializers.py:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

class TMyusersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source='id.username',read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = TMyusers
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'device')
```

In view.py:

```
class MyUsersList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = TMyusers.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TMyusersSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
```

What I want is that only autentificated users can read only their data, but now if I am autentificated I retrive a data list of all users.
I dont know how I can implemented.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I fixed it.

I made a Filtering against the current user;

```
class MyUsersList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = TUsuariosSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return TMyusers.objects.filter(id=user)
```